# Permalinks, how to show them in post

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

So I created page

```
www.example.com/NEWS/
```

and I want all the posts from that category to show up there. It does that, but when I add a post (NEWS), the link is :

```
www.example.com/newpost/
```

I want to show it as

```
www.example.com/NEWS/newpost/
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a post category called "News", you can setup your permalinks to be like:

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

This will make any post under that category include `/news/` in the permalink

Comment: worked :) thx...

Comment: if it worked then you should 'accept' it as the correct answer.